# having multiple instances of blocks with different settings in D7

Tags: 7, blocks

I have activated [Multiblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiblock) module, create an instance of one custom block.
The admin/structure/block/instances say my new block instance is not 'multiblock enabled'

The doc say 
https://www.drupal.org/node/353565

> To get around this, you can make a block "multiblock enabled". To do
>   this, you have to first add an $op to your hook_block called
>   'mb_enabled'. It should always return the string 'mb_enabled'.

I don't quite get how to do that and I have tried that with no effect

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block().
 * @param string $op one of "list", "view", "save" and "configure"
 * @param integer $delta code to identify the block
 * @param array $edit only for "save" operation
 */
function amu_hal_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

    // set up an empty array which will contain the block contents
    $block = array();

    switch ($op) {
        case "list":
            // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
            $block[0]["info"] = t('On This Date');
            break;

        case "view":
            break;

        case "save":
            break;

        case "configure":
            break;

            case 'mb_enabled':
                return 'mb_enabled';
                break;
    }

    return $block;
}
```

Is hook_block present in D7 at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hook_block in Drupal 7. However if you take a look at your README file inside your D7 version of multiblock module, you can find how to do it:

> Example implementation of hook_block_info:
>
> ```
> function hook_block_info() {
>   $blocks['powered-by'] = array(
>     'info' => t('Powered by Drupal'),
>     'weight' => '10',
>     'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
>     'mb_enabled' => TRUE,
>   );
>   return $blocks;
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks, can u explain how to persistently save the settings per instance then? so far it was : function amu_hal_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
 switch ($delta) {
  case 'last_hal_publications' :
   variable_set ( 'docids_publis', $edit ['docids_publis'] );

Comment: @Matoeil I'd try this first: https://www.aram.cz/article/integrating-your-custom-module-multiblock-drupal-7

Comment: @Matoeil did it work for you?

Comment: i will check this afternoon.i was off

Comment: @Matoeil you're welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

to precise more, if it can help anyone:

```
    function amu_hal_block_info() {
            $blocks ['last_hal_publications'] = array (
                    'info' => t ( 'Liste des dernières publications HAL' ) ,
                    'mb_enabled' => TRUE,
            );

    function amu_hal_block_view($delta = '',$edit=array()) {
        $block = array ();

        $suffix = '';
        if ($edit && isset($edit['multiblock_delta'])) {
            $suffix= '_' . $edit['multiblock_delta']['#value'];
        }

        switch ($delta) {

            case 'last_hal_publications' :
                $block ['subject'] = t ( 'Dernières publications' );
                $docids = variable_get ( 'docids_publis' . $suffix);
                //code
                break;


   function amu_hal_block_configure($delta = '',$edit=array()) {


    $suffix = '';
    if ($edit && isset($edit['multiblock_delta'])) {
        $suffix= '_' . $edit['multiblock_delta']['#value'];
    }

    $form = array ();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'last_hal_publications' :
            $form ['docids_publis'] = array (
                    '#type' => 'textarea',
                    '#title' => t ( 'Publis significatives' ),
                    '#description' => t ( 'Pour des publis significatives, entrer un HAL docid par ligne' ),
                    '#default_value' => variable_get ( 'docids_publis'. $suffix, '' ) 
            );
            break;

function amu_hal_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
    $suffix = '';
    if ($edit && isset($edit['multiblock_delta'])) {
        $suffix= '_' . $edit['multiblock_delta']['#value'];
    }

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'last_hal_publications' :
            variable_set ( 'docids_publis'. $suffix, $edit ['docids_publis'] );
            break;


    }
}
```